# String comparison from command output

Tags: bash

I have a file containing the following text.

```
            channel: stable
  installed-version: 6.45.6
             status: finding out latest version...

            channel: stable
  installed-version: 6.45.6
     latest-version: 6.45.6
             status: System is already up to date
```

I am trying to do a string comparison of the text after the last  occurrence of status:

```
System is already up to date
```

**My script is as following:**

```
GOOD="status: System is already up to date"
STATUS=$(cat file.txt | grep  status | tail -1 | tr -d '\r' )

if [ "$STATUS" != "$GOOD" ]
then
     echo "There is a new version available"
else
     echo "You are up to date"
```

I noticed that the string assigned to $GOOD is 29 characters long and whereas $STATUS was 30 characters, so as per suggestion I piped both to XXD.

Noticed that $STATUS had 0d (carriage return) and used `tr -d '\r'` to remove it.

Now both strings match in HEX, but the comparison still fails.

```
Length of GOOD:37
Length of STATUS:37
00000000: 7374 6174 7573 3a20 5379 7374 656d 2069  status: System i
00000010: 7320 616c 7265 6164 7920 7570 2074 6f20  s already up to 
00000020: 6461 7465 0a                             date.
00000000: 7374 6174 7573 3a20 5379 7374 656d 2069  status: System i
00000010: 7320 616c 7265 6164 7920 7570 2074 6f20  s already up to 
00000020: 6461 7465 0a                             date.
```

Comment: You should use `bash -x`/`set -x` to debug that kind of error. With your current code there's a space after the colon that is included in the second field and makes the comparison fail

Comment: Searching for the whole "status: System is already up to date" string and using the success of this seach for your condition would also be easier.

Comment: thank you. Tried that but still fails, very weird.

Comment: Does [this](https://ideone.com/8UDsYO) work for you? You'd have to replace the `-` in the `grep` command by your `file.txt`. If it doesn't it means the command's output contains either tabulations instead of spaces or non-printable characters. But you should see those with `bash -x`/`set -x`

Comment: You can pipe the string to `xxd` to see exactly what characters it contains.

Comment: that works great, although I can't believe it still fails. let me update the question with the HEX

Comment: Did you test with `echo "$STATUS" | xdd`, double quotes can be important ? Try `set -x` before the `if` statement,

Comment: thanks Walter that did the trick, forgot about "" also had leading spaces. So the trick was to first remove the carriage return and then the leading spaces.

Comment: You have spaces before status. Use xargs instead tr -d '\r'.

Answer (score 0):

You have spaces before status. Use xargs instead tr -d '\r'.

```
GOOD="status: System is already up to date"

STATUS=$(grep status file.txt | tail -1 | xargs)

if [ "$STATUS" != "$GOOD" ]
then
    echo "There is a new version available"
else
    echo "You are up to date"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `pattern matching` with the `[[ .. ]]` command instead of
`[` or `test` command.
Here is a tiny example of the usage:

```
target="aaa"
string="   aaa___"

if [[ $string == *$target* ]]; then
    echo "match"
fi
```

You don't have to care about the leading/trailing extra characters with
the pattern matching.
Then you can say something like:

```
good="status: System is already up to date"
status=$(grep "status" "file.txt" | tail -1)

if [[ $status == *$good* ]]; then
     echo "You are up to date"
else
     echo "There is a new version available"
fi
```

Note that you don't have to double-quote the variables within the [[ and ]].
Hope this helps.

Comment: There's no difference between `==` and `=` in bash. The Compound Commands section of `man bash` describes the `[[ expression ]]` syntax and says "The = operator is equivalent to ==". The precaution one needs to take when using this syntax is to 1) use `[[` rather than `test`/`[` and 2) use wildcards (and other pattern meta-characters) in the right-side operand only, as the left side isn't interpreted as a pattern

Comment: @Aaron Thank you for updating me :). Surprisingly the description "The = operator is equivalent to ==" in the Compound Commands section of the bash man page first appeared with bash 4.3, although it seems to work since bash 2.